# rational solutions to an algebraic equation

Tags: number-theory

the equation in question:
$$x^n=x+n$$
or the polynomial
$$x^n-x-n=0$$
the problem is to find all rational $x,n ∈ Q$ s.t the equation is satisfied.
before taking the rational solutions i decided to try and solve it for integers.
if you take n to be a picked natural number you get a sequence of polynomials:
$$n=0, -x-1 = 0, x=-1$$
$$n=1, -1 = 0$$
$$n=2, x^2-x-2, x=2,-1$$
from here i haven't managed to find any more rational solutions neither to prove they don't exist.
if we take x to be a picked natural number we get a sequence of equations:
$$x=0, -n=0, n=0$$
$$x=1,2-n=0,n=2$$
$$x=2,2^n -n-2 =0,n=2$$
from here i didn't find anymore rational solutions neither to prove they don't exist.
can i get help solving the problem? in the restrictive integer form or in the general rational form?

Comment: Maybe you can write $x = p/q$ as an irreducible fraction ($p$ and $q$ coprime) and then multiply by $q^n$ and check arithmetic conditions for $x$ to exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You described all possible solutions, below is explanation of that.

Every rational root of polynomial with leading coefficient that equals to $1$ is indeed integer root (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), so we need to find all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{n}-x=n$.
You are already considered cases $0\leq x,n\leq 2$, so let us consider other ones.

If $x=-1$ then $n=(-1)^n+1$ and $n=2$.

If $|x|\geq 2$ then $2^{n}-2\leq |x^n-x|=n$, but if $n>2$ we have $2^n=4*(1+1)^{n-2}\geq 4(1+1*(n-2))=4(n-1)>n+2$, that led us to contradiction